# How to get values with similar indexes from a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
ls = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

How can I get values from the two included lists at index `1`? Is it possible to make a list with those values?

The result should be `[1, 4]`

Comment: ```val=[i[1] for i in ls]```?

Comment: Most welcome. Consider accepting my 'answer' if it solves the problem

Answer (score 3):

> How can i get values from 2 included lists with index 1?

You can use a simple list comprehension and indexing.

```
val=[i[1] for i in ls]
```

Comment: @ABP Regarding your suggested edit, that's a totally different solution. You can post your  own answer if you'd like. As well, the `and` is incorrect; you want `[ls[0][1], ls[1][1]]`.